# Emacs Regex replacement

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

In my latex file, I defined

```
\newcommand{\replace}[2]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{#1} }\textcolor{blue}{{#2}}}
```

Just to highlight changes. So in my paper draft, there are many occurrences of

```
\replace{old text}{new text}
```

Now the paper is accepted, and I want to get a clean version. How can I use emacs Regex replacement to change all of them to

```
new text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is to modify your replace command so that it only prints the new text:

```
\newcommand{\replace}[2]{#2}
```

---

Otherwise, I would do this with a keyboard macro such as the following:

```
C-s           ;; isearch-forward
\             ;; self-insert-command
replace{      ;; self-insert-command * 8
RET           ;; newline
<left>        ;; backward-char
ESC <C-right> ;; forward-sexp
C-SPC         ;; set-mark-command
C-r           ;; isearch-backward
\             ;; self-insert-command
replace       ;; self-insert-command * 7
RET           ;; newline
C-w           ;; kill-region
2*C-SPC       ;; set-mark-command
ESC <C-right> ;; forward-sexp
DEL           ;; delete-backward-char
C-u C-SPC     ;; set-mark-command
C-d           ;; delete-char
```

The logic behind this keyboard macro is that you search for `\replace{` commands, then use `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` to move around balanced pairs of `curly brackets.

**Edit**: note that the binding for `forward-sexp` is traditionally written as <kbd>C-M-<right></kbd>, but such a key press might be intercepted by your window manager (a very frequent behaviour for Linux boxes at least). It is therefore often easier to type <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>C-<right></kbd> instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the command `query-replace-regexp` (`M-x query-replace-regexp` or `C-M-%`) with the following pattern:

```
\\replace{.+?}{\(.+?\)}
```

and the following replace string:

```
\1
```

Note the question mark within the curly braces, which makes the search lazy (non-greedy), which means that it matches as few characters as possible.

Comment: I don't think such a solution will work in cases where '}{' appears within the arguments. For example: `\replace{$\frac{1}{2}$}{$\frac{1}{3}$}`

Comment: Thank Erik for the suggestion. The issue raised by Francesco is valid. I did experience such problem.